# PHP Fatal Error Failed opening required File No such file or directory

Tags: php, warnings, admin, fatal-error, required

I get to see this error on my website.....I do not really know how to fix this as I am not a pro at php :/

This is what I get:

> Warning: require(/www/opencart1/fifafinity/comfifafinity/adminpanel123456//adminpanel123456/files/core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/opencart1/fifafinity/comfifafinity/adminpanel123456/index.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/www/opencart1/fifafinity/comfifafinity/adminpanel123456//adminpanel123456/files/core.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /www/opencart1/fifafinity/comfifafinity/adminpanel123456/index.php on line 4

It would be great if someone could explain me how to fix it, thanks!

**Code**

```
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/adminpanel123456/files/core.php";

    //header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

    $plugins = array('style' => false, 'jquery' => false);

    if(is_file(ROOT."/pages/$page/config.php"))     include(ROOT."/pages/$page/config.php");
    if(is_file(ROOT."/pages/$page/$page.css"))  $plugins['style'] = "/pages/$page/$page.css";
    if(is_file(ROOT."/pages/$page/$page.js"))   $plugins['jquery'] = "/pages/$page/$page.js";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="author" content="Curtis Crewe">

            <title>Management Panel - <?=ucfirst(str_replace("_"," ",$page));?></title>

            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="/design/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
            <link href="/design/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="/design/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="/design/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <?  
            if($plugins['style'])   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"screen\" href=\"{$plugins['style']}\" />";
            $userNav = array(
                "/dashboard" => 'Dashboard', 
                "/stats" => 'Stats',
                "/players" => 'Players',
                "/add_player" => 'Add Player',
                "/feed" => 'Transactions',
                "/withdrawals" => 'Withdrawals',
                "/deposits" => 'Deposits',
                "/customers" => 'Customers',
                "/accounts" => 'Accounts',
                "/add_accounts" => 'Add Accounts',
                "/packs" => 'Packs',
                "/add_pack" => 'Add Pack',
                "/settings" => 'Settings',
                "/logout" => 'Logout'
            );
            $nonAuthNav = array(
                "/login" => 'Login'
            );
        ?>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://js.pusher.com/1.12/pusher.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/design/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="/design/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="/design/js/global.js"></script>
            <?
                if($plugins['jquery'])  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{$plugins['jquery']}\"></script>";
            ?>
            <!-- Put this into a custom JavaScript file to make things more organized -->
            <script>
                $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
                });
                window.AjaxURL = "<?=HOME;?>files/ajax_framework.php";
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Sidebar -->
                <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Management Panel</a></li>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                                foreach($userNav as $link => $title) {
                                    if(ltrim($link,'/') == $page) {
                                        $class = "class='active'";
                                    } else {
                                        $class = "";
                                    }
                                    echo "<li ".$class."><a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a></li>";
                                }
                            } else {
                                foreach($nonAuthNav as $link => $title) {
                                    if(ltrim($link,'/') == $page) {
                                        $class = "class='active'";
                                    } else {
                                        $class = "";
                                    }
                                    echo "<li ".$class."><a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a></li>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- Page content -->
                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                            if(is_file(PAGES."/$page/$page.php")) {
                                if($page == "login") {
                                    include(PAGES."/dashboard/dashboard.php");
                                } else {
                                    include(PAGES."/$page/$page.php");
                                }
                            } else {
                                include(PAGES."/error_pages/404.php");
                            }
                        } else {
                            switch($page) {
                                case "login":
                                    include(PAGES."/login/login.php");
                                break;
                                default:
                                    include(PAGES."/error_pages/404.php");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you could start by posting your source code

Comment: please provide your index.php code i.e. some part

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, I'd suggest taking a look at **line 4** and seeing if the filepath the code is referring to exists.

Comment: @Fred-ii- here you go http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4359

Comment: @Abbas http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4359

Comment: @BenPearlKahan http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4359

Comment: Or perhaps better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php... Good luck!

Comment: @PeeHaa I do not have much php knowledge...